# How Determine the LOWEST build target for a class you wish to use- VS 201

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I would like to "use" the proximitydevice class in a simple app that I am testing. But I would also like to try and make that app as compatible with as many Windows versions as possible.

Currently my build target was .NET 2.0 but when trying to add the proximitydevice class, I have errors saying that not in namepsace.

How do I in visual studio 2019 (or elsewhere) match the lowest version of .net to the class I would like to use

AND where can I find the HIGHEST .net supported by windows versions.

Cheers,
Courtney.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice `ProximityDevice` is Windows 10 only as it is part of UWP (can only be used in UWP projects), so you should completely forget about .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am only new to windows programming and VS - UWP is too far detached from the operating system I wish to target - I now have a better understanding of .net CORE .NET UWP - frameworks and their dependencies. Although it would be great to see an interactive dependency chart if anyone knows of one. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> make that app as compatible with as many Windows versions as possible

For your requirement, you could create [.NET Standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) and write the processing logic in it. .NET Standard  is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations. However, [`ProximityDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice) api is xbox device only, so it could not use in a desktop app. Please check this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#list-of-apis) available to desktop apps. Unfortunately, `Windows.Networking.Proximity` is not in the above list.

> I now have a better understanding of .net CORE .NET UWP - frameworks and their dependencies. Although it would be great to see an interactive dependency chart if anyone knows of one.

For better understand, you could refer Immo's [**Making it easier to port to .NET Core**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/) Microsoft dev blog.